# Put() vs Flush() in Kafka Connector Sink Task

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to send the data in a batch to a NOSQL database using Kafka Sink Connector. I am following https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect documentation and confused about where the logic of sending records has to be implemented. Please help me in understanding how the records are processed internally and what has to be used Put() or Flush() to process the records in a batch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When a Kafka Connect worker is running a sink task, it will consume messages from the topic partition(s) assigned to the task. As it does so, it repeatedly passes a batch of messages to the sink task through the `put(Collection<SinkRecord>)` method. This will continue as long as the connector and its tasks are running.

Kafka Connect also will periodically record the progress of the sink tasks, namely the offset of the most recently processed message on each topic partition. This is called *committing the offsets*, and it does this so that if the connector stops unexpectedly and uncleanly, Kafka Connect knows where in each topic partition the task should resume processing messages. But just before Kafka Connect writes the offsets to Kafka, the Kafka Connect worker gives the sink connector an opportunity to do work during this stage via the `flush(...)` method.

A particular sink connector might not need to do anything (if `put(...)` did all of the work), or it might use this opportunity to submit all of the messages already processed via `put(...)` to the data store. For example, [Confluent's JDBC sink connector](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html) writes each batch of messages passed through the `put(...)` method using a transaction (the size of which can be controlled via the connector's consumer settings), and thus the `flush(...)` method doesn't need to do anything. [Confluent's ElasticSearch sink connector](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html), on the other hand, simply accumulates all of the messages for a series of `put(...)` methods and only writes them to Elasticsearch during `flush(...)`.

The frequency that the offsets are committed for source and sink connectors is controlled by the connector's `offset.flush.interval.ms` configuration property. The default is to commit offsets every 60 seconds, which is infrequent enough to improve performance and reduce overhead, but is frequent enough to cap the potential amount of re-processing should the connector task unexpectedly die. Note that when the connector is shutdown gracefully or experiences an exception, Kafka Connect will always have a chance to commit the offsets. It's only when the Kafka Connect worker is killed unexpectedly that it might not have a chance to commit the offsets identifying what messages had been processed. Thus, only after restarting after such a failure will the connector potentially re-process some messages that it did just prior to the failure. And it's because messages will potentially be seen at least once that the messages should be idempotent. Take all of this *plus* your connectors' behavior into account when determining appropriate values for this setting.

Have a look at the [Confluent documentation for Kafka Connect](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) as well as open source sink connectors for more examples and details.

Comment: Hello @Randall Hauch, Above is a nice answer to understand how connect commits the offset. In the application I work, in case we have exception we re-try multiple times (configurable value) and after which we stop the task assigned to connector using `System.exit(0)` which will mostly be a graceful shut down. So, in that case i.e. because `System.exit(0)` was invoked, are offsets committed until the place where exception was seen or until the previous batch  (i.e. until the current batch of records) because of which `System.exit(0)` was invoked ?